# Invalid JSON String on response in android-apollo

Tags: android, json, kotlin, graphql, apollo-client

I send simple mutations and I was expecting JSON but in response string like that :

```
{
   facebook=https://www.facebook.com/, 
   linkedIn=https://www.linkedin.com/  
}
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
object HelperJSON {
    private var gson: Gson = Gson()
    fun fetchSocialUrls(jsonString: String): SocialLoginUrlInfo {
        Log.e("JSONHelper ", "Enter: " + jsonString)
        return gson.fromJson(jsonString, SocialLoginUrlInfo::class.java)
    }

    fun toJsonString(simpleObject: Any?): String = gson.toJson(simpleObject)
}
```

In Presenter:

```
socialLoginUrl = HelperJSON.fetchSocialUrls(HelperJSON.toJsonString(response.data()?.socialLoginUrls()))
```

Answer (score 0):

This seem to be URL parameters, use this method to convert back to JSON String format:

```
public static String urlParamsToJSON(String urlParams) {
    urlParams = urlParams.replaceAll("=", "\":\"");
    urlParams = urlParams.replaceAll("&", "\",\"");
    return "{\"" + urlParams + "\"}";
}
```